# CSS: Wrong body size detected..?

Tags: css

I've been trying to make a custom lockscreen work with the iPod Touch 4G. It works quite well, but for some reason it sets the wrong body size. Normally, the body size will fit in the size of the screen but when I move the lockscreen (I move the lockscreen to unlock) I can clearly see '[body spaces](http://s1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc490/KeyMs92/Black%20Areas%20Around%20Lockscreen/?albumview=slideshow)' near the bottom and right edge of the lockscreen. In this case it's colored black because I set the body `background-color` to black. I tried setting the body size manually but it doesn't have any effect.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/daanodinot/7fuAN/) you have the complete code, although note that it works perfectly fine with a PC screen.

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15185020/WP7%20Lockscreen%20core2go.zip)'s another WP7 lockscreen which doesn't have this issue. Maybe you can find something particular in the CSS that might solve the problem. BTW, the three folders in next to the html/js are irrelevant, but just so you have the full theme.

Comment: I [reworked](http://jsfiddle.net/v8jEt/) what you were doing to leave the body element out. I'm not familiar with the iPod/iPhone, so I'm not sure how it will render the body if you pull it away. Are you going for a transparent body as the lockscreen tears away?

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it leaves the same amount of space on the right and bottom side. I'm actually wondering IF it is actually the body you see or just some 'mess' caused by iOS/Winterboard...

Comment: Just added another WP7 lockscreen theme to my initial post. It doesn't have this problem, so maybe you can find something in it...

Comment: You can make custom lock screens for iOS? I had no idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you using the viewport meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`

There are variations of that. For further explanation: [David Calhoun](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag)

Comment: That solved it! (didn't expect that to work) Thanks so much :D Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You tried to reset the css? It's probably a browser issue of padding or margin...
I cant really test, but try do add the reset.
You can search on google or use this one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

Set your image to `display:block` - an image is an inline element by default, and will be affected by setting your body to `font-size:50px`.

Comment: I added `img { display:block; }` but it had note effect. Note that the image is perfectly fine, it's just the body itself that's too large. I just don't get it.. even if I specify e.g. the body width 100px it makes no difference.

Comment: Are you really sure? I'm pretty confident this fixes the padding at the bottom of the image (though not the right edge, which I can't test since I don't have an iPhone thingy). Try setting the font-size on the elements itself, instead of on body, and see if that helps.. Or try setting the image as a background.

Comment: You're right that the `img { display:block; }` fixes the bottom padding you seen on the PC. However, it's unrelated to the problem I experience on the iPod/iPhone. Your other two suggestion didn't help either :( If it helps, I added another WP7 lockscreen theme that doesn't have this problem. Maybe you can find something in it.

Comment: The only obvious difference I can see is that `div#background` is set to `position:absolute` with `z-index:0` in the working lockscreen - you could give that a try? You may have to give `div#labels` a positive z-index like `z-index:99` too.